# How to get height from a fragment and set up the height of a viewpager?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm in troubles.

I'm trying getting the height from a fragment like following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/container_frag_informacoes_detalhes"
tools:context="br.com.magazineluiza.mobilevendas.userinterface.detalhesproduto.FragInformacoesDetalhesProduto">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_frag_information_detalhes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/loren_ipsum"/>
```

Which gets a big text from the @string/loren_ipsum.

I'm trying to get the height of it, but I can't.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewbyId(R.id.tv_frag_information_detalhes);
final int height = tv.getHeight();
```

in the onCreateView.

Comment: I've already tried to do it, but it returned 0. I've still tried to get the height of the linearLayout, the fragment view and the measureHeight of both. I've also tried to get it in the ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(), but it returned 0 too.
I've just tried to create a custom viewPager and edit the onMeasure, but it resized with a wrong value

Comment: Try View.post()